# Initialize accordion with angularjs and materializecss

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, materialize

I've got this accordion made using materializecss framework:

```
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
                    <li id="licollapse" ng-repeat="single in packageNames">
                        <div class="collapsible-header">{{single.name}}</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body"><p>{{single.name}}</p></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

and really i tried in several ways to init this accordion but without success! I tried to write in the html view:

```
<script>$('.collapsible').collapsible();</script>
```

and it not worked, i tried create in my controller

```
$scope.collapsible = function() {
             $('.collapsible').collapsible({
                 accordion : false // A setting that changes the collapsible behavior to expandable instead of the default accordion style
             });
         };
```

and call `collapsible` function in `ng-init` of the accordion and it not worked. The only one solution i found is call that function in `ng-click` in the `collapsible-header` but it's not best way because it works only at the second click.. How can i solve?

Answer (score 2):

When you are forced against your dying wish to call external jQuery frameworks or use jQuery in your Angular Application, then the best approach would be to do so in a directive!!!

The DOM should never be touched in your controller, instead, the state of your data in the controller should update the view.

So in this case we can create a simple directive that will have access to that element and call the function in question:

```
app.directive('collapsify', [collapsifyFn]);

function collapsifyFn(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
     return {
       pre: function preLinkFn(scope, element, attrs) {
         //if executed here collapsable only is called on an empty <ul>
       }, 
       post: function postLinkFn(scope, element, attrs) {
         function linkFn(scope, element, attributes) {
           debugger;
           $(element).collapsible({accordion: true});
         }
       }
     }  
    }
  }
}
```

An important thing to note here:

#### Use case for Pre and Post Link:

So because you are generating your `<li>`'s via an ng-repeat, you need to ensure that you are calling `.collapsible` in your link function **after** `ng-repeat` has rendered the `<li>`'s to the DOM.

Because of rendering priority, a simple `link:` would cause the `ng-repeat` `link:` to execute after, making your collapsable function not work properly. The purpose of `post:` is that it executes the `linkFn` after its children's `linkFn` has already executed.

Therefore you are accurately calling `.collapsible` on a "completely rendered dom".

Now that we have created our superfancy `collapsify` directive, we can attach it to the dom.

```
<ul collapsify class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
   <li id="licollapse" ng-repeat="single in packageNames">
      <div class="collapsible-header">{{single.name}}</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><p>{{single.name}}</p></div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

#### Example From Codepen:

```html
<p data-height="268" data-theme-id="0" data-slug-hash="meoWEK" data-default-tab="result" data-user="TheLarkInn" class='codepen'>See the Pen <a href='http://codepen.io/TheLarkInn/pen/meoWEK/'>Using Collapsible MaterializeCSS</a> by Sean Larkin (<a href='http://codepen.io/TheLarkInn'>@TheLarkInn</a>) on <a href='http://codepen.io'>CodePen</a>.</p>
<script async src="//assets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think your answer is the best i've found until now, really thank you. But unfortunatelly it's not working yet :( . My accordion appears with an ng-if.. Do you think could be the problem? Maybe it's not rendered from the dom..

Comment: I also tried put some console.log() in the directive; one in pre and one in post. Seems that the only one called is in pre. The console log in post is never called. Is it normal?

Comment: Do you have a code example that you can share? Also did you look at the codepen that I was using? Feel free to provide some more examples if you can.

Comment: Also try switching the `ng-if` to `ng-show` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should wait with calling your materialize code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.collapsible').collapsible({
      accordion : false
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it in this way

```
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
   <li id="licollapse" ng-repeat="single in packageNames">
       <div class="collapsible-header">{{single.name}}</div>
       <div class="collapsible-body"><p>{{single.name}}</p></div>
    </li>
   <script>
//Instert this just after closing </li>             
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.collapsible').collapsible({
       accordion: true 
      });
     });
    </script>
</ul>
```

It will work for sure :)